# How to create an equation from linear interpolants

Tags: interpolation

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) Wikipedia article on Linear Interpolation. The third figure down depicts a data set

```
0 0
1 0.8415
2 0.9093
3 0.1411
4 -0.7568
5 -0.9589
6 -0.2794
```

which I got from checking out the Gnuplot [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Interpolation_example_linear.svg). In the article it talks about this formula

\begin{align}
y = y_{0 }+ (x - x_{0})\frac{(y_{1 }- y_{0})}{(x_{1} - x_{0})} = \frac{y_{0}(x_{1} - x) + y_{1}(x - x_{0})}{(x_{1} - x_{0})}
\end{align}

Now, if I wanted a function like $y = mx + b$ to plot this data, i.e., to draw the "curve" in the diagram, it seems I would have to "glue together" the individual segments or *linear interpolants* somehow. Would it be something like this?

\begin{align*}
 s(x) = \left\{ 
   \begin{array}
    {r@{\quad \mathrm{if} \quad}l} \frac{y_{0}(x_{1} - x) + y_{1}(x - x_{0})}{(x_{1} - x_{0})}  & \, 0 < x < 1, \\
               \!\! \frac{y_{1}(x_{2} - x) + y_{2}(x - x_{1})}{(x_{2} - x_{1})}  &  1 < x < 2, \\
               \ldots 
   \end{array} \right .
 \end{align*}

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but they didn't create an equation for the linear interpolant version. What you've given is for the polynomial interpolation version that creates a "curvy curve" version of the data, i.e., not really what I'm asking.

Comment: So to actually create an equation, what I've suggested in the OP, which stays linear, is appropriate? The section on spline interpolation in the Wikipedia article seems to follow this style.